# ListView selected Item binding not work

Tags: xaml, listview, mvvm, selecteditem

I have a listview in uwp , and a view model that declare pataient_List and selected_patient in this. my listview show itemsource but I don't know why my listview do not show selected item.

```
 <ListView   ItemsSource="{Binding pataient_List}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding selected_patient, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding name_to_show_menu, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

viewmodel is

```
public class patient_view_model : notify_property_changed_base
    {
        public patient_view_model(patient  patient_param)
        {
            pataient_List = new ObservableCollection<patient>();
            load_patient(); // this function put patients in pataient_List
            selected_patient = patient_param;
        }

 public patient selected_patient
        {
            get { return _selected_patient; }
            set
            {
                if (_selected_patient != value)
                {
                    _selected_patient = value;
                    RasiePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
public ObservableCollection<patient> pataient_List { set; get; }
```

Comment: have you tried to put a breakpoint in the setter of your "selected_patient", and check if it actually hits is when you select an item from the list?

Comment: @alessalessio Yes, I put a break point ,really selected_patinet has value and when I select a new patient from listview the selected_patient change again

Comment: I don't see the method  implementation  for the RaisePropertyChanged method ... but i guess you need to pass the PropertyName:   RasiePropertyChanged("selected_patient")

Comment: @alessalessio its esist in my code

Comment: public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void RasiePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string fielName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(fielName));
            }

        }

Comment: i added my answer. it works on my project, let me know please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve issue with this one answer.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) 
 { 
 if (this.name_to_show_menu == (obj as patient).name_to_show_menu) 
    return true; 
 else  
    return false; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

One cause could be that the selected item must be one of the objects in the `pataient_List`.

Another cause is perhaps because you're setting the `selected_patient` in the constructor of the view model which is definitely before you bind the view model to the view. So, why not trying to set the `selected_patient` after you bind the view model to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about the ItemTemplate in the ListView.

```
 <ListView   ItemsSource="{Binding pataient_List}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding selected_patient, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Black">            
</ListView>
```

.NET doesn't have a clue about how you want your data to be displayed, so it just calls the ToString() method on each object and uses that to represent the item. Override the ToString() method in the patient object to display what you need. Here is the code:

```
public class patient
    {
        public string name_to_show_menu;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.name_to_show_menu;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but this did not solve my issue, we write in my viewmodel  selected_patient = patient_param; and i want to show this patient_param in selectedItem of my listveiw and this not happen

Comment: i created a small project in WPF and copy-paste your code your code. it wasn't working. i made the modifications i wrote you and it works. So, either your real code is different or the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Dear  @alessalessio  I write this code in WinRT in Universal Windows Platform, I write this codes       <ListView   ItemsSource="{Binding pataient_List}" 
                            SelectedValuePath="name_to_show_menu"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding selected_patient.name_to_show_menu,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> and its work but I need selected item. I mean , selected object not a string

Comment: @nik, would you be able to upload your case in a repository somewhere, so i can have a look at it?

Comment: public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
    if (this.name_to_show_menu == (obj as patient).name_to_show_menu)
                return true;
            else return false;
        }